# A given package is installed but spyder won't see it

Tags: installation, module, spyder

I installed statsmodels using command prompt. First of all i installed pip using these command in the command prompt :

```
curl https://bootst/rap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

and

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then i installed statsmodels using this command in the command prompt :

```
python -m pip install statsmodels
```

When i write `pip3 list`in` the command prompt it tells me that statsmodel is installed :

```
C:\Users\cg276622>pip3 list
Package         Version
--------------- -----------
numpy           1.26.4
packaging       24.0
pandas          2.2.1
patsy           0.5.6
pip             24.0
python-dateutil 2.9.0.post0
pytz            2024.1
scipy           1.12.0
six             1.16.0
statsmodels     0.14.1
tzdata          2024.1
```

But when i run `import statsmodels as sm` in spyder, it says "no module named statsmodels".

In the command prompt i run `pip show statsmodels`  and it says :

```
C:\Users\cg276622>pip show statsmodels
Name: statsmodels
Version: 0.14.1
Summary: Statistical computations and models for Python
Home-page: https://www.statsmodels.org/
Author:
Author-email:
License: BSD License
Location: C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pandas, patsy, scipy, scipy
Required-by:
```

I run `import numpy` and it works in spyder. When i run `numpy.__file__` in spyder to get the location of numpy it says `C:\\Program Files\\Spyder\\pkgs\\numpy\\__init__.py'`

What can i do for spyder to import statsmodels ?

I tried to close and open spyder but it didn't worked.
I tried to restart my computer, it didn't worked either.